# Dynamic Templating for InfoWindows failing

Tags: google-fusion-tables, infowindow

I used customized infowindows with my Google fusion table. To have information display conditionally, I used dynamic templating, as described here:
https://support.google.com/fusiontables/answer/3081246?hl=en

Recently, the infowindows stopped working, they display as blank. I think the issue is related to the dynamic templating, because if I switch to the normal window it displays okay.

Has something changed with Google's dynamic templating?:

{template .contents} 
{/template})

Even Google's demo isn't working: https://www.google.com/fusiontables/data?docid=1ZJE87ylGzbXZ0STzc2RuQ5uprjhUZPTntsxBguY

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing it too. I've filed it with the team to take a look.

Comment: That's good news. Any way I can help speed up the process? I use the feature for a map of coal ash in Illinois (http://prairierivers.org/coalashmap) and none of the data is displaying. We were hoping to use the map as a tool to inform the public.

Comment: A fix has been identified and it should go out later today.

Comment: Yep, I just noticed. Thank you!

Comment: I'm finding a new error and not sure how to reach you. I'm using a template for Infowindow styling on a fusion table map. Sometimes, when I open the template to modify the content, it will open the default code instead of my code. Once I accidentally saved it, and I lost everything. The solution is to close the "Change Info Window..." window and then open it again, and the template will re-appear.